# Oracle error message when trying to get tables from informix database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, database-connection, informix

I created new data source to access an informix database over an odbc data provider(informix 3.33; 32bit). Testing this connection succeeded so i created a new connection manager (new connection from data source) to use it for my ADO NET destination task. When i try to select a destination table it takes about 10 secounds of processing to get the following error:

> ===================================
>
> Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager
>   'Test'. Could not create a DbProviderFactory class for the provider
>   invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Verify that this provider
>   is installed correctly on this computer. (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> ===================================
>
> Could not create a DbProviderFactory class for the provider invariant
>   name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Verify that this provider is
>   installed correctly on this computer.
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%u00ae+Visual+Studio%u00ae+2008&ProdVer=9.0.30729.1&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.SR&EvtID=CouldNotGetFactory&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.ConnectionManagerUtils.GetConnectionTypeFromInvariantName(String
>   providerInvariantName)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.ConnectionManagerUtils.GetInvariantNameFromConnectionType(String
>   connectionType)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineUtils.GetActiveConnection(ConnectionManager
>   connectionManager, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.ComboBoxWithTables.FillTableOrViewComboBox()
>
> ===================================
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.RuntimeFieldHandle.GetValue(Object instance,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle fieldType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringType, Boolean&
>   domainInitialized)    at
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, Boolean
>   doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)    at
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String
>   providerInvariantName)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.ConnectionManagerUtils.GetConnectionTypeFromInvariantName(String
>   providerInvariantName)
>
> ===================================
>
> The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' threw an exception.
>
> ===================================
>
> Der Provider ist mit der Version des Oracle-Clients nicht kompatibel
>   (Oracle Data Provider for .NET)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory..cctor()

This is pretty strange, because the error output shows problems with `Oracle Data Provider for .NET` and i took an informix driver & my destination is an informix, too.

**I am using Windows 7 64bit, Visual Studio 2008, Informix 7.31C4**

For some reason the package uses the oracle driver.

Any suggestions?

-

I just updated the informix driver to version 3.5 and created new ODBC connections. Even after that the error stays the same. This is pretty weird.

Comment: Could you be using the wrong DSN? Perhaps you have a user DSN and a system DSN with the same name but different configurations?

Comment: Are you using the correct bit version? As in 32 bit and 64 bit versions?

Comment: @Pondlife I can only find one DSN with this name. It is a system DSN displayed in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. No 32bit user DSN and no 64bit user or system DSN with this name. I think the 32 bit driver should normally work for me doesnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the proper bit-level driver.  If the calling app is 64-bit, you will need to use a 64-bit driver, if it's 32-bit, you'll need to use the 32-bit driver.  My suspicion is you have a 32-bit driver and a 64-bit app, hence why it cannot find the driver since they're not the same bit-level.  Either install the 64-bit driver, or recompile the app as a 32-bit executable.